# High-resolution icon for file in Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, icons

I am looking for a method exactly like `-[NSWorkspace iconForFile:]` but which returns the icon in a higher resolution if possible.  In particular, I have an app which makes use of QuickLook to display previews of files, and I'd like it to fall back to the file icon if no quick look plugin is available.  Using the `iconForFile:` method, however, yields a small 32x32 icon.  Is there a better method around?  One that returns an `NSImage` or `CGImageRef` is preferred, but less accessible methods might be fine too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The returned image of `-[NSWorkspace iconForFile:]` contains multiple representations, including higher resolution ones.

If you try drawing it at 512x512 it will automatically pick the appropriate representation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way to make icon bigger:

```
NSImage * icon = [NSWorkspace iconForFile:yourPath];
[icon setSize:NSMakeSize(64,64)];
```

Thats it. Good luck!

Comment: `-setSize` is fraught with peril and should be avoided unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: The code is from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Workspace/Articles/InformationAboutFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001004-39665